# Not able to update the context in after successful API call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to implement a simple login function to my project in NextJS and I am trying to use Context API to store the data of the user. I tried to update the context after the data is fetched from the back-end but its not updating. When it try to log it in the console it shows an empty object.

Here's what I have tried:

**UserContextProvider.js**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ });

    const storeUser = new_user => {
        console.log("User: ", new_user);
        setUser({
            username: new_user.name,
            email: new_user.email,
            image: new_user.image_link
        });
    }

    const showUser = () => {
        console.log(user);
    }

    const logout = () => {
        setUser({});
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, storeUser, showUser }}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default UserContextProvider
```

**[provider].tsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Container, CircularProgress, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { } from "@material-ui/icons";
import Router from 'next/router'
import UserContextProvider, { UserContext } from '../../components/UserContextProvider';

const styles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  error: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
}));

interface Props {
  provider: string;
  code: string;
  classes: any;
}

function LoginPage(props: Props) {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  const { storeUser, showUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  const googleLogin = () => {
    fetch("/api/login/google", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: props.code,
      }),
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((res) => {
        fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/account/social_login`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          mode: "cors",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id_token: res.id_token,
            provider: "google",
          }),
        })
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((response) => {
            localStorage.token = response.token;
            document.cookie = `token=${response.token}; path=/; max-age=${
              60 * 60 * 24 * 100
              }`;
            storeUser({
              name: response.user.name,
              email: response.user.email,
              image_link: response.user.image_link
            });
            //This shows an empty object
            showUser();
            Router.push("/")
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            setError(true)
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError(true)
      })
  }

  //This works
  React.useEffect(() => {
    storeUser({
      name: "wqygubcjqnc",
      email: "asbcascacsj",
      image_link: "asjbcjasnck"
    });
    showUser();
  });

  const facebookLogin = () => {
    fetch("/api/login/facebook", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: props.code,
      }),
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((res) => {
        fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/login`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            access_token: res.access_token,
            provider: "facebook",
          }),
        })
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((response) => {
            localStorage.token = response.token;
            window.location.href = "/";
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            setError(true)
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError(true)
      });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.provider == "google") googleLogin();
    else if (props.provider == "facebook") facebookLogin();
    else alert("Invalid login provider");
  }, [])

  const classes = styles()

  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        {error ? (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography className={classes.error} variant="h6" color="error">
              Something went wrong. Please try again. If the problem still
              exists, contact the administrator.
          </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        ) : (
            <React.Fragment>
              <CircularProgress size={"4rem"} />
              <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                Logging you in
          </Typography>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
      </Container>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}


export const getServerSideProps = async (context: any) => {
  return {
    props: {
      provider: context.params?.provider,
      code: context.query.code,
    },
  };
};

export default LoginPage
```

I am currently using only Google login so please kindly ignore the facebook login function.

Answer (score 0):

actually the context value is not showing the latest value,as you logging the context just after setting it, it is not updated,
 whenever you update the React Context, any components who are consuming the context are Re-rendered with updated context value , so what we can do is  separting the logic into separate handlers which will get invoked when the context is updated with the user response by using useEffect

```
/* in Login page component*/

    const { user, storeUser, showUser } = useContext(UserContext);

    const handleLogin = () => {
       //any logic for handling login 
       showUser();
       Router.push("/")       
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // will get called when the user response is updated
        handleLogin()
    }, [user]);

    // in similar way for error     
    useEffect(() => {
       setError(true)
    }, [error]);

  /*in function googleLogin just update the context value , 
     and the handling of the login functionality will be handled by the useEffect and 
     handleLogin function */

    const googleLogin = () => {
        //rest of the code  
         storeUser({
              name: response.user.name,
              email: response.user.email,
              image_link: response.user.image_link
         });
    }
```

Comment: I actually tried that. I used a temporary page to check if the context had updated. But it didnt show any change. Your suggestion still led to logging of an empty object in the console.

Comment: actually i tried in the code sanbox, and its working
 https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-snow-vuel3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark 
you can check it out

Comment: Does this mean there is an issue with server side rendered apps in next.js? I too am able to update and store and modify the context in a separate page but it does not work when I do the same in the above mentioned [provider].tsx file.

Comment: it should work on server side rendered apps as well, can you check whether you are getting correct response from the fetch API call , or getting undefined from the fetch call itself.

Comment: I am getting proper response from the server. I have double checked it.